# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\tan x}{x}\, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I had spent one hour trying to do this integral with no luck.

Here is a list of things I Tried and ended up with 0=0 in end

1. Feynman trick by introducing $e^{-bx}$ into integrand
2. Feynman trick with putting b as a factor into tan(bx) inside the integral
3. integrating by parts (I wrote tan as sinx/cosx and integrate the $\sin x$ part and differentiated the $\cos x/x$ part)

Comment: There is no evaluation of this (definite) integral in terms of elementary functions, one may be able to use a computer to evaluate an antiderivative in terms of, say, polylogarithms but this is the best that can be achieved.

Comment: Looks like: $\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{4}} \frac{\tan (x)}{x} \, dx=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{2^{3-4 k} \left(-1+4^k\right) \zeta (2 k)}{(-1+2 k) \pi }=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{2^{3-4 k} \psi ^{(-1+2
   k)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(-1+2 k) \pi  (-1+2 k)!}$ where: $\psi$ is digamma function.

Answer (score 3):

This function does not have an analytical antiderivative, and I doubt that even the definite integral has one.

If we compare to the similar

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin(x)}xdx,$$ you need an ad-hoc function (the *integral sine*) to get an expression, namely $\text{Si}(\frac\pi4)$, which does not have a simple form. There is no corresponding *integral tangent*. This is by no means a proof, just an intuition.

Comment: WA doesn't give a closed form answer either.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a quadrature form, for example, Simpson's rule with $a=x_0$ and $b=x_n$.

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx \approx 
\frac{h}{3}\left(f(x_0) + 4f(x_1)+2f(x_2)+ 4f(x_3)+2f(x_4)+\cdots+4f(x_{n-1}) + f(x_{n})\right)$$
where $$h = \frac{b-a}{n}$$ and $x_i=a+ih$, $i \in \Bbb N, 1\le i\leq n$.
We have $h=\pi/3$ and $$f(x)=\frac{\tan\left(x\right)}{x},$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\tan\left(x\right)}{x}\,dx\approx \frac{1}{3}h\left(f(0)+4f(x_{2})+f(2\pi/3)\right)\approx 0.849$$
being

$$x_2=0+2\frac{\pi}3=\frac{2\pi}3$$